# Impossible to get cookie on a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

i'm making an express JS server with cookie. I never worked with cookie so this is my first time :)

when user login i send cookie to him :

```
res.cookie('pseudo', list[i].pseudo, {
                  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 3000,
                  httpOnly: true
              });
res.cookie('email', list[i].email, {
                  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 * 3000,
                  httpOnly: true
              });
```

When i use my reqest /getCookie for seeing the cookie i have :

> { Token: 'exampletoken',
>     pseudo: 'test',
>     email: 'test@test.test' }

my code for seeing the cookie :

```
var about = function (req, res) {
var cookies = require('cookies');
   console.log(req.cookies);
}
module.exports = about;
```

But when i used it for the index page i get no output you know why ? :'(

Here my index code :

```
var index = function (req, res) {
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
require('remedial');

marqueur = {};
marqueur.pseudo = "login";
marqueur.pseudo = req.cookies.pseudo;

console.log(req.cookies);
console.log(req.cookies.pseudo);

page = fs.readFileSync("./temp/index.html");
page = page.supplant(marqueur);
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
res.write(page);
res.end();
}

module.exports = index;
```

and here in my server file :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var express = require('express');
require('remedial');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('temp'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
const port = 443;
```

THANKS !!!!

Comment: Your code is looking funny, usually tho' you don't send cookies .. You only set them as a middleware.

Comment: so how can i get it for the username for exemple

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't told express how to parse the cookies. [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) is an express middleware which means it needs to be configured *before* you attempt to access the cookies e.g.

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
...
app.use(cookieParser());
// now add your cookie routes
```

Comment: i already write it, sorry i forget to say it, edited, even with that it doesnt work